# mips nested procedure with jr $ra

Tags: assembly, nested, mips

I'm trying to calling `FUNC` and return its value back to `xintersect`. I think using `jr $ra` should return to the caller but it jumps to the end of the code. I cannot modify `FUNC`, because it is a given sample test case. Any idea? Below is my MIPS code:

```
 .globl FUNC
FUNC:  
    mul   $t0, $a0, $a0
    addi  $v0, $t0, -16
    jr    $ra
# expect 4 in $v1
main:  
    la $a0, FUNC
    li $a1, 0#a
    li $a2, 100#b
    b  xintersect
xintersect:
    subu $s0, $a2, $a1
    sltiu $t3, $s0, 1
    add $s5, $0, $a0
    bne $t3, 1, whileLoop
    #return the value in $v1
    add $v1, $a1, $0
    jr $ra
whileLoop:
    addu $s2, $a1, $a2
    srl $a0, $s2, 1#m in $a0
    jr $s5
    slt $s2, $0, $v0
    beq $0, $s2, ifLoop
    addu $a2, $0, $a0
    b whileLoop
ifLoop:
    addu $a1, $0, $a0
    b whileLoop
```

Below should be the C code:

```
int xintersect(int (*f) (int), int a, int b) {
 /* f(a) ≤ 0 ≤ f(b), a ≤ b */
 while (b-a > 1) {
     int m = (a+b)/2;
     if (f(m) <= 0) a = m; else b = m;
     }
 return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jr $ra` relies on the return address having been placed in `$ra`, but you're calling `FUNC` using `jr $s5` which doesn't set `$ra`. Use `jalr $s5` instead.

The `b xintersect` in `main` should probably be `jal xintersect`, because otherwise the `jr $ra` in `xintersect` won't work. Also keep in mind that `xintersect` must save `$ra` somewhere (e.g. on the stack) if it needs to both call `FUNC` and then be able to return back to `main`.

It also looks to me like you've got an infinite loop in `xintersect`. Once you enter `whileLoop`, there's nothing that will exit the loop.

Comment: The thing this I cannot modify `main` either, it is given with the `FUNC`

Comment: Well, the `main` routine is broken. So you need to ask your professor or TA how you're supposed to return back to `main` if `main` doesn't call `xintersect` in a correct way.

Comment: Now I add the terminate condition to stop the `while` loop and store `$ra` in a temp register(`add $t7, $ra, $0`) before using `jalr $s5`. And I store it back to `$ra` when I need to use `jr $ra` to back to `main`(`add $ra, $t7, $0`). This gives me the correct output at least. Just wondering is it legal to do it in MIPS?

Comment: Normally you'd use the stack to save `$ra`, but I suppose using `$t7` is fine if you know that you're not calling any code that will modify `$t7`.

Comment: `jal xintersect` would be worse.  Currently main tail-calls it, so when it returns, it returns to main's parent.  If you used `jal`, it would return to after the jal, then execution would fall into `xintersect:` because main doesn't end with `jr $ra`  (or restoring `$ra`).

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop has no `EXIT`.

To engage `jr` you need `jal` so i have written that too
your `$ra` is not saved in stack in `XINTERSECT`:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra, 0($sp)
```

and RESTORE BACK

```
lw $ra,$sp
addi $sp,$sp,4 #restore the pointer too
```

---

```
globl FUNC
FUNC:  
    mul   $t0, $a0, $a0
    addi  $v0, $t0, -16
    jr    $ra
    #expect 4 in $v1

main:  
    la $a0, FUNC
    li $a1, 0#a
    li $a2, 100#b
    jal xintersect

xintersect:
    subu $s0, $a2, $a1
    sltiu $t3, $s0, 1
    add $s5, $0, $a0
    bne $t3, 1, whileLoop
    #return the value in $v1
    add $v1, $a1, $0
    jr $ra
whileLoop:
    addu $s2, $a1, $a2
    srl $a0, $s2, 1#m in $a0
    jalr $s5
    slt $s2, $0, $v0
    beq $0, $s2, ifLoop
    addu $a2, $0, $a0
    b whileLoop
ifLoop:
    addu $a1, $0, $a0
    b whileLoop
```

Comment: If `xintersect` returns right away, execution will fall through from main into `xintersect` again.  That can't be right; tailcall with `b xintersect` is surprising but at least possible.

Comment: @frankenapps - good guess at how to format that text, but I'm pretty sure the "and" was English, not the MIPS mnemonic.  And that code doesn't make sense at the top of the file, it looks like it's a suggestion to do that in `xintersect`, despite the big code block *not* having that change.